# How to retrieve the caption of a table (longtable)

Tags: captions, longtable

I want to repeat the caption of a `longtable` on different pages.

1. Is there any way (other than defining a new variable to save the caption) to get it.
2. How can I get rid of the extra line after the caption for the first time, i.e., the header of the `longtable` in the first page.

MWC (you can replace images ):

```
\documentclass[preprint, 12pt]
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   % colored rows
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\caption{Step by step execution trace of Algorithm \ref{algo:CWM}}
\label{tab:example01Table}


% %\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}

%
\\       % <=====  I want to get rid of this line please 
\rowcolor{gray}
\# & Heap & Tour \\ 
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{(Cont.) Table \thetable: Step by step execution trace of Algorithm }} \\

\rowcolor{gray}
\# & Heap & Tour \\ 
\hline\hline
\endhead

%

0 &  Empty & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t00.pdf} \\\hline
1 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h01.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t01.pdf} \\ \hline
2 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h02.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t02.pdf} \\ \hline
3 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h03.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t03.pdf} \\ \hline
4 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h04.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t04.pdf} \\\hline
5 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h05.pdf} & No Change \\ \hline
6 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h06.pdf} & No Change \\ \hline
7 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h07.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t07.pdf} \\ \hline
8 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h08.pdf} & No Change \\ \hline
9 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h09.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t09.pdf} \\\hline
10 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h10.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t10.pdf} \\ \hline
11 & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{h11.pdf} & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{t11.pdf} \\ \hline
- & - & \includegraphics[width=\mylength]{finalTour.pdf} \\ \hline

% %\end{tabular}

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: rather than say "MWC (you can replace images ):" it's more helpful to make the example not need them, use `\rule` or the `demo` option to `graphicx`

Comment: If I run your example I get `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ...int, 12pt}][{table}]\@clsextension 
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please always post minimal WORKING examples.

1. You can load the `nameref` package and then use it as in

   ```
   \multicolumn{3}{c}%
           {{(Cont.) Table \thetable: \nameref{tab:example01Table}}}
   ```
2. You can load the `caption` package and issue the command:

   ```
   \captionsetup[longtable]{aboveskip=0pt}
   ```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   % colored rows
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{aboveskip=0pt}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\caption{Step by step execution trace of Algorithm \ref{algo:CWM}}
\label{tab:example01Table}


% %\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}

%
\\       % <=====  I want to get rid of this line please
\rowcolor{gray}
\# & Heap & Tour \\
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
%
\multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{(Cont.) Table \thetable: \nameref{tab:example01Table}}} \\

\rowcolor{gray}
\# & Heap & Tour \\
\hline\hline
\endhead

%

0 &  Empty & \includegraphics{t00.pdf} \\\hline
1 & \includegraphics{h01.pdf} & \includegraphics{t01.pdf} \\ \hline
2 & \includegraphics{h02.pdf} & \includegraphics{t02.pdf} \\ \hline
3 & \includegraphics{h03.pdf} & \includegraphics{t03.pdf} \\ \hline
4 & \includegraphics{h04.pdf} & \includegraphics{t04.pdf} \\\hline
5 & \includegraphics{h05.pdf} & No Change \\ \hline
6 & \includegraphics{h06.pdf} & No Change \\ \hline
7 & \includegraphics{h07.pdf} & \includegraphics{t07.pdf} \\ \hline
8 & \includegraphics{h08.pdf} & No Change \\ \hline
9 & \includegraphics{h09.pdf} & \includegraphics{t09.pdf} \\\hline
10 & \includegraphics{h10.pdf} & \includegraphics{t10.pdf} \\ \hline
11 & \includegraphics{h11.pdf} & \includegraphics{t11.pdf} \\ \hline
- & - & \includegraphics{finalTour.pdf} \\ \hline

% %\end{tabular}

\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I must set the vertical skip manually?

Comment: @remo. For example, if you want `10pt` as a vertical skip, use `\captionsetup[longtable]{aboveskip=10pt}` and `\multicolumn{3}{c} {{(Cont.) Table \thetable: \nameref{tab:example01Table}}} \\[10pt]`

Answer (score 7):

Packages `nameref` or `zreftitleref` remember the caption titles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{aboveskip=0pt}

\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{zref-titleref, zref-user}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Table caption}\label{tab}\zlabel{tab}
  \end{table}

  \begin{longtable}{lll}
    \caption{Longtable caption}\label{longtab}\zlabel{longtab}\\
    nameref:& \nameref{tab} & \nameref{longtab}\\
    ztitleref:& \ztitleref{tab} & \ztitleref{longtab}
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remark:**

- The space below the caption is removed by the help of package `caption` as shown in [karlkoeller`s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157120/16967).

Comment: What about my second problem i.e., the extra space after the caption of the long table?